# Python pipelines duplicate checker, using "raise DropItem" but how do we make it pipe down?

Tags: python, python-pipelines

raise DropItem below is creating too much noise and outputting complete objects

**Question**: How can we make it output just the string? Or is there another Way to drop items in pipelines?

the result is now a whole object with all its values and cluttering the output. The wish would be to drop 1 item silently ... we used delete() before but this resulted in errors in later pipelines. Help appreciated

```
    # Duplicate checker based on https://scrapy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
    if item['sku'] in self.skus_seen:
        if "url" not in item or not item['url']:
            item['url'] = '???, plz store item url in spider'
        raise DropItem(f"Duplicate products {item['sku']} at {item['url']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

A populair question and answer ;)

It is given here

Implement

import logging
from scrapy import logformatter

class PoliteLogFormatter(logformatter.LogFormatter):
def dropped(self, item, exception, response, spider):
return {
'level': logging.INFO,
'msg': logformatter.DROPPEDMSG,
'args': {
'exception': exception,
'item': item,
}
}

[Scrapy - Silently drop an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527921/scrapy-silently-drop-an-item)